# Understanding CSS sprites and links

Tags: css, sprite

I have been researching how to use CSS sprites as image links, but I can't figure this out. I have a PNG (here: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta3Va.png] ) that has two images in it (for simplicity). I want each image to be act as an icon that can be linked to an external website (Twitter and Facebook). I set up my CSS like this:

**CSS**

```
#authorpage-links  ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}

#authorpage-links ul li {
    background: url("/links-authorpage1.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}

#authorpage-links ul li.twitter {
    background: url("/links-authorpage1.png") no-repeat 0 0; 
    width: 20px; 
    height: 14px; 
}

#authorpage-links ul li.facebook {
    background: url("/links-authorpage1.png") no-repeat -21px 0; 
    width: 14px; 
    height: 14px; 
}
```

...and my HTML like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="authorpage-links">
<li id="authorpage-links" class="twitter">
<a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/"></a>
</li>
<li id="authorpage-links" class="facebook">
<a target="_blank" href="http://facebook.com/"></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Now, 2 questions:

1) Is using a list to display these images the best way or should I use div's?

2) Is this an issue with my CSS IDs and classes?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your biggest problem is with the HTML.   You've repeated the same id (`authorpage-links`) three times but id's **must** be unique.

Comment: Another problem is your targeting.  This `#authorpage-links ul li.facebook` means that you're targeting an `li` with class `facebook` which is a child of a `ul` which is a child of an element with id `#authorpage-links`... yet your HTML reflects no such structure.

Comment: You're also using your `authorpage-links` CSS selectors wrong.  If you want to select a `ul` with an id of `authorpage-links`, you do `ul#authorpage-links`, not `#authorpage-links ul`.

Comment: @iambriansreed, please familiarize yourself with the differences between **comments** and **answers** on SO.  In other words, comments do not have to answer the question... **that's why I posted it as a comment!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a revision of your CSS (problems that I'll come to, later) to the following:

```
#authorpage-list {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#authorpage-list li {
    float: left;
}
#authorpage-list li a {
    background-color: transparent; /* I broke the background down into individual parts */
    background-image:    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta3Va.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    display: block; /* in order that the a elements could be assigned a width/height */
    border: 1px solid #f90; /* for diagnostic purposes while working on this, adjust to taste */
}

#authorpage-list #authorpage-facebook-link a {
    /* a specific selector, in order to be more specific than the previous
       selector which styled the defaults for the a elements in this position */
    background-position: -21px 0;
}​
```

And amending your HTML to the following:

```
<ul id="authorpage-list">
    <li id="authorpage-twitter-link" class="twitter">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/"></a>
    </li>
    <li id="authorpage-facebook-link" class="facebook">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://facebook.com/"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I came up with this: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ECBRM/2/).

​

---

## CSS problems

1. This is the biggest no-no insofar as HTML goes (or so far as I've ever been able to see, it's even worse than the `blink` tag): you have ***multiple*** examples of the ***same*** `id` in your HTML. An `id` ***must*** be unique within the document. If not, you have invalid HTML. Which causes problems with CSS, with JavaScript and...it's just *bad*.

   If you have multiple elements that need to share a property/style, or whatever, use a `class`, not an `id`.
2. Your selectors. `#authorpage-links  ul` should match a `ul` element within an ancestor element of `id="#authorpage-links"`. The `ul` is the element *with* that `id`. I'll ignore that its child elements also had that `id`, since I think I've covered that part. All your other CSS started off that base, which wasn't accurate, and so didn't work.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer to mention the duplicate id issue and why it's a problem.

Comment: @DavidThomas While I agree totally with multiple IDs being bad, for many reasons, they don't cause problems with CSS or Javascript in any browser. So if you use that as an argument, people may do some testing and conclude you're wrong. Just saying.

Comment: As to CSS, I've had some relatively, not *traumatic* (by any stretch), but...unexpected outcomes, when forgetting to move an `id` from one element to another to as an element role shifts in design. CSS all over the shop... As for JS? It depends on how you define 'problems,' I guess. If people re-use `id`s in the same document they tend to be surprised when `getElementById()` *doesn't* return *all* of them. Admittedly it's not as earth-shattering as leaving the AC running all day, but it has its impact. And its a trouble best avoided, I feel.

Comment: @DavidThomas Such a great explanation! Thank you! I'm experimenting with it now.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<li>` elements may be sized to 14x14, but you've got nothing in the `<a>` tags, so those'll shrink down to a 0x0 area, effectively making your list elements clickable areas invisible. You should probably put a space into the anchor tag, so there's SOMETHING to push them open, e.g.

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://facebook.com/">&nbsp;</a>
                                               ^^^^^^
```

Comment: easily fixable by setting height/width on the a's, or setting some overflow control. Either way, this is just as an example.

Comment: @iambriansreed, everyone can already see your fantastic answer so you don't need to keep pointing it out everywhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Your `a` link need to have a size. I did so in making the a's have a clickable area. Since your `lis` don't need a size i gave the size to the `a` links.

Replace your li css with:

```
ul#authorpage-links li a {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url("/links-authorpage1.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}

ul#authorpage-links li.twitter a {
    background-position: 0 0; 
    width: 20px; 
    height: 14px; 
}

ul#authorpage-links li.facebook a {
    background-position -21px 0; 
    width: 14px; 
    height: 14px; 
}
```

Also remove the id attribute from your `lis`.

"... fantastic answer ..." - Sparky672

Comment: @DavidThomas Yeah totally. I added the suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Why was my answer down voted? Anything wring I need to improve on or just being petty?